# Function returning 0 works, returning > 0 will crash the Programm

Tags: winapi, visual-c++

Im making a call to a function in an if statement

```
if (function(...)) {
    do some stuff...
} else {
    do something else...
}
```

the problem now is that when the function returns 0 the `else { ... }` block executes perfectly fine, but if the function returns something > 0 the programm will crash.

the function in question:

```
BOOL fnCheckRegistryKeyW(
    _In_ LPCWSTR lpSubKey,
    _In_ LPCWSTR lpValueName,
    _In_ DWORD dwEType,
    _In_ BYTE bEValue
) {
    HKEY hKey;
    DWORD dwType;
    BYTE bValue;
    DWORD dwlen = sizeof(DWORD);
    BOOL bReturn = FALSE;

    LSTATUS lsRKey = RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, lpSubKey, 0, KEY_READ | KEY_WOW64_32KEY, &hKey);
    if (!lsRKey) {
        LSTATUS lsRVal = RegQueryValueEx(hKey, lpValueName, 0, &dwType, (PBYTE)&bValue, &dwlen);
        if (!lsRVal) {
            if (dwType == dwEType && bValue == bEValue) {
                RegCloseKey(hKey);
                return TRUE;
            } else {

            }
        } else {

        }
    } else {

    }

    // If HKLM can't be read try HKCU
    hKey = NULL;
    lsRKey = RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, lpSubKey, 0, KEY_READ | KEY_WOW64_32KEY, &hKey);
    if (!lsRKey) {
        LSTATUS lsRVal = RegQueryValueEx(hKey, lpValueName, 0, &dwType, (PBYTE)&bValue, &dwlen);
        if (!lsRVal) {
            if (dwType == dwEType && bValue == bEValue) {
                RegCloseKey(hKey);
                return TRUE;
            } else {

            }
        } else {

        }
    } else {

    }

    RegCloseKey(hKey);
    return FALSE;
}
```

The function itself works fine, but it crashes the pragramm as soon as it has returned a  value > 0 and due to that the Codeblock inside the if statement dosen't get executed.

Comment: You appear to be overwriting the buffer that you pass to the registry api

Comment: @DavidHeffernan can you elaborate ?

Comment: You pass a buffer of length 1 to a function and the function will overwrite it if the value is greater than that length. You even tell the registry function that your buffer is 4 in length. I suggest you consult the docs for the registry api once more and look at the requirements for the buffer and length arguments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing a pointer to a single `BYTE` as the buffer for `RegQueryValueEx()` to write to, but you are setting `dwLen` to `sizeof(DWORD)` (4), allowing `RegQueryValueEx()` to write up to 4 bytes to a buffer that can only hold 1 byte.  You need to change `bValue` from a `BYTE` to a `DWORD`, or else set `dwLen` to `sizeof(BYTE)` (1) instead.

Otherwise, allocate the buffer dynamically.  Call `RegQueryValueEx()` once with its `lpData` parameter set to NULL, then allocate the buffer using the byte size reported on output, then call `RegQueryValueEx()` again with that buffer.

Comment: yeah I noticed my mistake later too (things like this should be obvious)
I don't know how I missed that, atleast it was just a typo, still thanks though